# Recycler unregisterAdapterDataObserver

Tags: android, kotlin

I implemented registerAdapterDataObserver for a Recycler object in a Fragment. I implemented this DataObserver so when data is added to the Recycler list, I can update a count that is displayed to the User.

```
baggageListAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            override fun onChanged() {
                super.onChanged()
                setBaggageCount()
            }
        })
```

Should I be implementing unregisterAdapterDataObserver someplace in the Fragment. Like in

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Fragment will outlive the RecyclerView.Adapter, it is unnecessary to unregister the listener.

If your design is clean, I think it should be unnecessary to listen to adapter changes. You could be observing the same LiveData/Flow/Flowable that is providing data to the adapter, or if you're not using a reactive pattern, then you could be updating that count in the same function that's used to change the backing data. It's kind of awkward to be using a view object as source of truth about data state.

Comment: Just a reminder, there are cases where observing the view makes sense. 
For example for some custom animations on the screen, you may want to run them when items appear on the screen not sooner.